# Show/Hide View using Slide Up and Down Animation

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

Still showing and hiding view like this:

```
if(isChecked)
{           
    linearLayoutMap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else 
{
    linearLayoutMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
}
```

but what if I have to show and hide using Slide Up and Slide Down Animation

Comment: use custom animations with animation objects..

Comment: show me your animation functionality..